# thread safety AbstractRoutingDataSource with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

how to use Multiple database connection on multiple threads..

I know how to use database connection with routingdataSource dynamically
but I think it is not thread safety Because the class is static.!!!

```
// first thread

ContextHolder.set("firstId");
mapper.select();
ContextHolder.clear(idFirst);


 // second thread

ContextHolder.set("secondId");
mapper.select();
ContextHolder.clear(idFirst);



public class ContextHolder {
  private static ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void set(String dbType) {
      CONTEXT.set(dbType);
  }

  public static String getClientDatabase() {
      return CONTEXT.get();
  }

  public static void clear() {
      CONTEXT.remove();
  }
}
```

like this code.

```
    public class Poller implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getNext() {
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            ContextHolder.set(dbConnectionId);
            List<Map<String, Object>> list = blogMapper.findAll(params)
            ContextHolder.clear();
            return list;
        }

    ....
    }
```

Comment: spring creates a connection per thread so there should not be any problem with that. What issue do you observe? Why do you think this is the problem you have?

Comment: Hello. Roman Konoval. 
 I have 10 threads for getting data from shard databases. actually it is 10 relication db table.
 It means one thread for one db connection. x 10 
 I want to get all of tables data with threads for Elasticsearch bulkingprocessor.

 If I set ContextHolder.set(dbConnectionId). it will be changed in every thread.
 Because I think ContextHolder`s method is static.
 in this case how to get all of data with each threads . please let me know any information.

 thanks!!

Comment: First of all, do not clarify the question in comments. Edit the question itself. You still did not explain what issue you have. You even did not ask any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the

```
 private static ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

create a threadlocal variable. It means that what you put inside is bound to a specific thread and when you get something it is what in this thread that is returned.

For instance, in thread 1 you set:

```
CONTEXT.set(1);
```

in thread 2 you set:

```
CONTEXT.set(2);
```

and later thread print what inside with a

```
CONTEXT.get();
```

it will print `1` for thread 1 and `2` for thread 2.

So now, if you use a standard synchronous model, it is fine as long as you don't forget to clean the value when you enter and/or exit the request.

As soon as you use async (reactive, executor, ...) it will fail as part of your process will be run on another thread.

Comment: Thanks!!

It was my mistake.
I just forgot ThreadLocal`s meaning.

thanks a lot wargre